# How to redirect STDIN of background process?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, io, stdin, nohup

In my Ubuntu, i run java application in background. I use bash script to run it and now it looks like:

```
nohup java -jar app.jar &
exit 0
```

The problem that i want to be able to write an input string to my application, without making it foreground, from different terminals/sessions. Something like

```
echo "mytext" > /appdir/in
```

How should i change my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**main.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [ ! -p in ]; then
    mkfifo in
fi
tail -f in | java -jar app.jar
```

Send command to the application with following syntax

```
echo "command" > /home/user/in
```

Comment: This is good solution, but I do not get how to get `stdout` from the app.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
mkfifo /appdir/in
nohup java -jar app.jar < /appdir/in &
exit 0
```

The test:

```
$ ./startapp.sh
$ printf "%s\n" "mytext" >> /appdir/in
$ cat nohup.out
mytext

$
```

There is additional control to add in order to manage the lifecycle of the **/appdir/in** named pipe.

Comment: Good try but it does not work (with or without nohup). My application simply not running (not started).

Comment: @DmitrjA So the application start needs to be troubleshooted? The test section here is a real test. Do you have any error message on the console, in the appilcation log file, in nohup.out? My own app.java read line from STDIN and write it to STDOUT.

Comment: If i run `java -jar app.jar < pipe.in ` java is not started, and terminal hangs untill  Ctrl+Z or Ctrl+C

Comment: try **java -jar app.jar < pipe.in &** instead

Comment: Its same, but without hanging. I  don't have application sources, but it's normal command line tool. Tried to use "/proc/PID/fd/0", no success, but i could use it incorrectly.

Comment: The behavior of you java application is not the same as my simple app.java (on Linux). I could not imagine, at time of writing, what could be the root cause, sorry.

Comment: It works now, i am not sure what changed, but application ignores any other command except the most first one. I tried adding \n to the end of my "echoes".